# Shell script to drop PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, shell

I use these commands:

```
su - postgres // change user to 'postgres'
dropdb db1    // drop database 'db1'
exit          // change user back to root
```

These commands work well from console, so I created a small `sh` file with the same lines and added a `-x` chmod to execute the file. However, when I execute the Script, only the first line and changes the user to `postgres` and stops there with the blinking cursor. Then, if I type `exit` to return back to `root`, it shows the message: `dropdb: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  role "root" does not exist`.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Try `PGUSER=postgres dropdb db1`.

Comment: …or simply [`dropdb -u postgres db1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-dropdb.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u postgres psql -c 'drop database IF EXISTS test'
exit
```